# Movie where a blob-like alien crawls into a man’s mouth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching a movie as a child. The one scene I remember was a clear blob like alien crawled into a man’s mouth and the man was frantically trying to drink alcohol in the middle of the store.

He was Caucasian and in his late 40’s with little hair and he kept opening beer and trying to drink it but he couldn’t because of the alien. The store was a run down kind of gas station.

But for the life of me I can’t remember the movie.

Comment: We really could use more details... if you free--associate, can you remember anything else? Was the man Caucasian? From the United States? Was it gin he was drinking?

Comment: He was in his late 40’s caucasion with little hair and he kept opening beer and trying to drink it but he couldnt cause of the alien . The store was a run down kind of gas station.

Comment: When were you a kid? 1990? 1970? 30 BCE? We’ve got no idea :o

Comment: I would say it was around 2004 or 2005 that i had seen it

Comment: Street Trash: Liquor Store that disolves people into goo.

Comment: Also: I) Night of the creeps and ii) slither both have blobs that crawl into mouths.

Answer (score 3):

I am gonna go out on a limb here and suggest [Constantine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04pJsqLXrj4)

Everything except the alien blob is there and if its literally the only scene you can remember I could kinda see someone misremembering the ending where the alcohol is coming out of his mouth as an alien blob going into his mouth

Answer (score 0):

It's called "The Blob", they remade it a few times. The Blob (1958), Beware! The Blob (1972), and The Blob (1988). Most likely the last one, because that's the one where it shows people dissolving tye most.